# Best Approach in projecting Database

Tags: database-design, oracle11g

I got List of Products. Now there is four types of Products. There is still a chance that there will be in future another Product. Each of product type has common fields but also has unique which are only in this type. Eg.

```
PRODUCT_1
A varchar - common column
B varchar - common column
C int - unique for this type
D int - unique for this type

PRODUCT_2
A varchar - common column
B varchar - common column
E double -  unique for this type
F varchar - unique for this type
```

I thought to create table PRODUCT which will contains meta data of all  product types.

```
PRODUCT
ProdId int - PK
ProdType - int
A varchar
B varchar
```

And second table called PRODUCT_EXTENSION which will be defining rest of products fields:

```
PRODUCT_EXTENSION
ProdExtId - PK
ProdId - FK
FieldName varchar
FieldValue varchar
```

Is this good way to create such a structures? I little bit afraid of performance of SELECTS statements. And not even sure how to create SELECT which will return the row with columns:

```
SELECT A, B, C, F
```

Maybe I should just create separate tables for each type of product?

```
TABLE PRODUCT_1
TABLE PRODUCT_2
```

Please advice what is better or maybe there is another approach?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're looking for:

- If you're adding product definitions dynamically then the first structure you proposed works. The drawback is that you'll lose the ability to use indexes and DB optimization because you're abstracting the table structure out of the DB, e.g. the product columns became table rows for the DB.
- If your products are well defined and limited you can have a master PRODUCT table with all the common columns and related tables for each product with the specific product columns. Now, the drawback is that you cannot add a new product without rewriting the DB schema.